# How can I use Cordova without installing Android Studio?

Tags: android, cordova

I use an old computer for development, and my current specs doesn't meet Android Studio's System requirements.
I am a newbie, and only know some JS/HTML5. And I'm trying to enable oAuth for Firebase Auth services for Android.

I downloaded the Commandline Tools from https://developer.android.com/studio/ (far at the bottom of the page) and tried to use *sdkmanager.bat*, but I can't make it accept commands. I added its Path to the Environment variable "path", and then tried using Windows PowerShell. But writing any command will just make it start over again. (maybe it was something foolish of me)

Then I downloaded and installed Gradle.
After that when I write `cordova requirements` I get the following result:

```
Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: not installed
No android targets (SDKs) installed!
Gradle: installed C:\Users\Sparsha\Desktop\gradle-6.5-all\gradle-6.5\bin\gradle
Some of requirements check failed
```

I am not sure how Android SDK installed became true, but Android target is not installed (Don't know how to install).

Also, using `cordova build` gives me the following results:

```
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Sparsha\Desktop\commandlinetools-win-6514223_latest (DEPRECATED)
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the User Manual chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Process command line: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -Duser.country=IN -Duser.
language=en -Duser.variant -cp C:\Users\Sparsha\Desktop\gradle-6.5-all\gradle-6.5\lib\gradle-launcher-6.5.jar org.gradle.launcher.daem
on.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 6.5
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get
full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
C:\Users\Sparsha\Desktop\gradle-6.5-all\gradle-6.5\bin\gradle: Command failed with exit code 1
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever you downloaded from that URL is **not** needed. That is probably the SDK for Android Studio.

To setup your Cordova tools to develop Cordova apps with either Visual Studio or your favorite text editor like Notepad++, [follow this detailed guide](https://www.andreszsogon.com/setting-up-your-environment-for-apache-cordova-apps/) which I created earlier.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks! That's a nice article.. However I somehow managed to install Android SDK after installing Chocolatey just to find out that my computer is out of memory. But I installed Linux and it works great there!

Wait, does Android SDK Manager have an exe file? I thought I can only run it using commands.

I absolutely need this file after upgrading my computer. Its really strange that I could not find this in Google's website. Thanks!

Comment: It had the SDK Manager and AVD Manager which was later removed from Google to force developers to install Android Studio. But you can still download it from the provided links and use it perfectly fine in Windows, macOS and Linux.